# how to check if arrays are in separated arrays or in the same one

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with 2 values (the outer part is the array the inner part are the values)

[image]

And then i have four other arrays with each containing 4 values:

[image]

Now what i basically want to check is: if the 2 values of the first array are in one of the four arrays together then do an action. so for example:

[image]

I also want to run a different action if the items are in separated arrays like this:

[image]

How can i do this?

Comment: Awesome. Do you want show us your code so we can see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Im looking for something that can point me in the right direction. Like is there a name for this? or anything at all

Comment: What exactly is the logic? If the two are in *any one*? Or *exactly one*? What if multiple arrays match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first case, you could use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect):

```
$arr = array('foo', 'bar');

$test1 = array('foo', 'bar', 'three', 'four');
$test2 = array('foo', 'two', 'three', 'four');
$test3 = array('one', 'bar', 'three', 'four');
$test4 = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');

$result = array_intersect($arr, $test1);
var_dump($result);
```

If the result count matches `$arr`, then you know both values from `$arr` are present in whichever test array you're comparing against. If that fails, then you can perform your second test using [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_intersect):

```
$merged = array_merge($test1, $test2, $test3, $test4);
$result = array_intersect($arr, $merged);
```

Again, if the result count matches `$arr`, then you know both values were found amongst the multiple arrays. If you want to know exactly which two (or more) arrays the values are in, then you could just compare two at a time within a loop that cycles through every permutation.

Answer (score 2):

For the first case, you can do it like this:

```
$a = [1,2];

$b = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [5,6,7,8],
    [9,2,1,2],
    [0,1,2,3]
];

foreach ($b as $arr) {
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($a as $outer_arr) {
        if(in_array($outer_arr, $arr))
            $count++;
    }

    if($count >= count($a)) {
        var_dump('yes');
    } else {
        var_dump('no');
    }
}

/* Output:
yes
no
yes
yes
*/
```

Hope this helps!